# Django custom filters not working in included templates

Tags: django, django-templates

Not sure if I've done something wrong but if I try to use a custom filter in an included template fragment I'm getting "invalid filter"

If I try the filter on the main template it works fine.

Is this a known limitation/bug?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll need to `{% load %}` in the included template as well.

So, if base.html is calling `{% include "sub.html" %}`, then you'll need to have the `{% load custom_filters %}` tag at the top of sub.html as well.

Comment: Why it is not working if tried to load in base template file?

Comment: And if I'm loading the admin template ?